# How to get the exit status of a Java program in Windows batch file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, exit-code

Analogous to the `$?` in Linux, is there a way to get the exit status of a program in a Windows batch file (`.bat`)? 
Say for example the program has a `System.exit(0)` upon successful execution, and a `System.exit(1)` upon a failure, how do I trap these exit values in a `.bat` file?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [%ERRORLEVEL%](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm).  Don't you love how batch files are clear and concise? :)

Answer (score 29):

Something like:

```
java Foo
set exitcode=%ERRORLEVEL%
echo %exitcode%
```

It's important to make this the absolute next line of the batch file, to avoid the error level being overwritten :)

Note that if you use the

```
IF ERRORLEVEL number
```

"feature" of batch files, it means "if the error level is greater than or equal to `number`" - it's not based on equality. I've been bitten by that before now :)

Comment: I had a slight problem with this answer ... AFAIK, you can't use space in the set command, so it should be set exitcode=%ERRORLEVEL%. Anyway, making that change worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

Raymond Chen has a good blog post named [ERRORLEVEL is not %ERRORLEVEL%](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx). Worth checking out.

Also worth noting is that the REM command which most people think of as comments, really aren't. The REM command is a nop command which **always succeeds**. After a REM, the error level is always 0. So

```
willalwaysfail.bat
REM unless you insert a comment after it
if errorlevel 1 goto fail
```

will never fail...

Answer (score 1):

mostly answering **bulgar**'s question, but complementing the other answers:

for %ERRORLEVEL% to work you need to have the *command extensions* activated in Windows (it's the default).
For one session:

```
cmd /E:on
```

or permanently in the registry

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\EnableExtensions = 0x01
```

for more details:

```
cmd /?
```

[]]

Answer (score 0):

Most of the usual external command operations return **ERRORLEVEL** 0 and this usually (but NOT invariably) indicates that no error was encountered:

```
c:\> dir
...
c:\> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```