# Running Java programs off a trigger

Tags: java, triggers, scheduler

It is a little high level question and I'm looking for possible solutions. 
So I've a Java program A and another Java program B. They are supposed to run in a VM. Now there is one constraint - that B shouldn't run until a file, say `C.xml`, is generated by A and a few minutes after. How can I solve this problem ? 
One solution might be using some scheduler which schedules A and then runs B based of a trigger (I've no idea which scheduler can be used).
And another is write a service that runs on the VM and waits for `C.xml` to be generated. Once its generated, kicks-off B.
Any other ideas ? (or any help/comment on the two ideas that I've suggested).

Comment: Does A stop running soon / directly after generating the file? If so, you can just put A and B sequentially in a batch file / shell script (depending on the OS).

Comment: @ssnobody Windows Server 2012

Comment: @Dukeling then how do I know if A generated the file ? (we don't want to run B if A failed to generate the file)

Comment: Is there a way (in Java) for A to tell - hey the file is done - B you can run after a minute.

Comment: You could do this using [WMI Event Monitoring](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ff730927.aspx) and listening for `__InstanceCreationEvent`. If you can change the source code for both programs, then after A is done generating C.xml it could send a execute or send a message to B. Perhaps you could try directly invoking the method, using Java Message Service, or a network socket.

Comment: Call [System.exit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)) with a non-zero parameter to indicate that A failed and just [check for this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887066/how-to-get-the-exit-status-of-a-java-program-in-windows-batch-file) in your script.

Comment: Thanks - Does any know if Jenkins can do this? Like trigger B after verifying if A has done generating C and then say wait for a minute.